# test suite not overwrite DefaultSharedPreferences

Tags: android, testing, sharedpreferences

I am using the SettingsActivity created by AndroidStudio (extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity, which extends PreferenceActivity).  My preference values are getting stored in the DefaultSharedPreferences (pkg-name_preferences.xml).

I'd like to be able to specify a different name for the DefaultSharedPreference file when the test suite is running.  This would prevent the test suite from over-writing any preference values I may have set during normal use of the app.

Is it possible to do this?  (Just to be clear: I am able to detect if the test suite is running, but I don't know how to specify a name for the DefaultSharedPreferences.)

I found some old posts that suggest:

```
PreferenceManager prefMngr = getPreferenceManager();
prefMngr.setSharedPreferencesName("my_name");
```

getPreferenceManager() was deprecated in API 11, and if I try to use it anyway it returns null.

Or maybe there is some other way to achieve my objective (test suite not over-writing app's preference values)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The boiler-plate SettingsActivity includes inner classes for each sample preference group (for example, GeneralPreferenceFragment).  These classes extend PreferenceFragment.

I added a class that extends PreferenceFragment and specifies a name for the preference file:

```
/**
 * This (abstract) fragment is a super-class for the category-specific fragments.
 * It sets the shared preferences file name.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
abstract private static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // set the shared preferences file name
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("my file name");
    }
}
```

I changed GeneralPreferenceFragment (and the 2 other inner classes) to extend MyPreferenceFragment, rather than PreferenceFragment.